# No Debugging symbols found error even after enabling -g option

Tags: gdb, makefile

Small portion of the `Makefile`

```
CC=gcc -g -MMD
EXE=MegaCli

all:$(EXE)
LDFLAGS=-02
SOUCE_DIR=$(UNIV_VIVA_CLI)lib/linux/

LINK=g++

Ctm.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)Ctm.cpp
       $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(SOURCE_DIR)Ctm.cpp
```

Before someone else have logged the same post. But my `Makefile` is same as the answer given to that post. But still I am getting error `No Debugging Symbol found`. Then I tried the below command too.

```
(gdb) exec - file MegaCli
error>No symbol table is loaded use the file command
```

Please give some solution to the above.

Comment: There is a typo which suggests that either you are not showing us the real makefile, or the makefile is not doing what you think it's doing. What happens when you compile by hand (i.e. on the command line)? What if you use a simpler makefile?

Comment: Does the link line (the one that produces the executable) include `-g`?  If not, that's the trouble.  (And, in principle, use `gcc` to compile C code and `g++` to compile C++ code.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you are invoking GDB. Don't do this:

```
gdb
(gdb) exec - file MegaCli   # I am not sure what this even means!
```

Do this:

```
gdb MegaCli
(gdb) run
```